# Flash Player limit on total memory

Tags: flash

I wan to know, does Flash Player have limit on total memory used by all swf instances?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not necessarily. The flash module(s) will keep requesting memory from the operating system until it cannot allocate it anymore. When this point is reached, the OS will either kill the program or force it to release some of its memory.

As a developer, you should limit the amount of memory you use, but Flash does not force you to.